# Send email using smtp client in c#

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

the following code gets recipients email, email subject and email body from a table and creates the emails and sends them to a pickup directory. there is a db connection class that I did not include here, but I invoke it in the code below. 
The code below runs fine however I am wondering if it could be improved to run faster considering It will be used to send 10000 plus emails.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace SendEmails
{
class SendEmail
{
    private class EmailsList
    {
        private class listData
        {
            public string email;
            public string email_header;
            public string email_body;
            public string email_guid;
        }
        public void data()
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlData;
            ArrayList Emaillist = new ArrayList();
            sqlData = new SqlCommand("SELECT email, email_header, email_body, email_guid FROM dbo.vw_emails ", con.openconnection()).ExecuteReader();
            // loop through the emails table and load arraylist
            while (sqlData.Read())
            {
                listData itemData = new listData();
                itemData.email = sqlData[0].ToString();
                itemData.email_header = sqlData[1].ToString();
                itemData.email_body = sqlData[2].ToString();
                itemData.email_guid = sqlData[3].ToString();
                Emaillist.Add(itemData);                
            }               
            sqlData.Close();
            con.closeconnection

            foreach (listData itemData in Eamillist)
            {
                //SEND EMAIL *****************************/
                spSendMail(itemData.email, itemData.email_header, "me@yahoo.com", itemData.email_body, itemData.email_guid);
                //DO THE UPDATE *********************/
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("up_emailLog", con.openconncetion());
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_GUID", itemData.email_guid);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.CloseConnection();

            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
           EmailsList sEmails = new EmailsList();
            sEmails.data();                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo.Err_Log](exception, insdt) VALUES('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "','" +  "','"+ DateTime.Now + "')", Con.OpenConnection());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.CloseConnection();                 
        }
    }
    // Send Email Method
    public static void spSendMail(string recipients, string subject, string from, string body, string email_guid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, recipients))
            {
                    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                    mailMessage.Body = body;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxxxxx.xxxx.zo");
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                    smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = "\\\\exchange_server\\pickup";
                    //Create eml file and send it to pickup directory
                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);                               
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo.Err_Log](exception, communication, insdt) VALUES('" + ex.Message.ToString() +"','" + recipients.ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')", con.OpenConnection());
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Con.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .NET 2.0 or later, then you can use the `SmtpClient.SendAsync` method, which will create a new thread to send the email on and free up the main thread for more processing.

Read [SmtpClient.SendAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for documentation.

You should also look into using Generics if you are using .NET 2.0 or later, it will provide type safety for your `Emaillist` object, but not much performance improvement, because you were not getting the unboxing hit common with `ArrayList`, because you were not using value types.

Here is what your `EmailList` code might look like using Generics `List<T>`:

```
List<listData> Emaillist = new List<listData>();

while (sqlData.Read())
{
    listData itemData = new listData();
    itemData.email = sqlData[0].ToString();
    itemData.email_header = sqlData[1].ToString();
    itemData.email_body = sqlData[2].ToString();
    itemData.email_guid = sqlData[3].ToString();
    Emaillist.Add(itemData);                
}
```

The above code will generate a compilation error if you try to add any other type than `listData` to the `Emaillist` list.

Comment: Hi Karl,Thanks for the answer. However I don't think I can use SendAsync because this method takes two arguments mailMeassage and Object userToken and I don't know what userToken to use or what it is.

Comment: @ama did you read the documentation?  `userToken` is just passed to the completed event so you can identify which message completed.  You can pass `null` as the value if you don't need a callback when the method completes.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks fro the replies, but I am not sending the emails I am just writing the .eml files into a pickup directory. from what I read, SendAsyc is used when the emails are sent directly to the recipients. do I really need to use threading here even if I am just writing .email files? Thanks for you help in this

Comment: You are asking for ways to make your code faster or more efficient. This will make it more efficient, because it will fire off the message and then have the potential to do more work immediately. I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.